# Infinite norm of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the fallowing operator:

$Tu= \int_0^1u(x)dx-2\int_1^2u(x)dx+\int_2^3u(x)$

where $T:E \rightarrow R \,,E=L^1([0,1]) $

and I want to calculate $||T||_{E'} $

If I am right, $ E'=L^\infty([0,1]) $

and this means that I have to calculate $||T||_\infty$

=================================================

This is what I have done:

The operator is linear:

$T(u+v)=\int_0^1(u(x)+v(x))dx-2\int_1^2(u(x)+v(x))dx + \int_2^3(u(x)+v(x))dx$

$=\int_0^1u(x)dx + \int_0^1v(x)dx-2\int_1^2u(x)dx-2\int_1^2v(x)dx+\int_2^3u(x)dx+\int_2^3v(x)dx$

$=T(v)+T(u)$

$T(au)=\int_0^1au(x)dx-2\int_1^2au(x)dx+\int_2^3au(x)dx$

$=a\int_0^1u(x)dx-2a\int_1^2u(x)dx+a\int_2^3u(x)dx$

$=a(\int_0^1u(x)dx-2\int_1^2u(x)dx+\int_2^3u(x)dx)$

$=aT(u)\, \forall a \in R $

I showed that it is bounded (continuous):

$||Tu||=max_{x \in [0,3]}|\int_0^1u(x)dx-2\int_1^2u(x)dx+\int_2^3u(x)|$

$ \le max_{x \in [0,3]}|\int_0^1u(x)dx|+max_{x \in [0,3]}2|\int_1^2u(x)dx|+max_{x \in [0,3]}|\int_2^3u(x)dx| $

$ \le max_{x \in [0,3]}\int_0^1|u(x)|dx+max_{x \in [0,3]}2\int_1^2|u(x)|dx+max_{x \in [0,3]}\int_2^3|u(x)|dx $

$\le 4||u||$

Now I know:

$||T||=sup_{u \in C([0,3]), u \neq0} \frac{|Tu|}{||u||_\infty} \le 4$

and I want to show that $||T||>=4$

Comment: Try to break your math over multiple lines.  It extends far beyond the right side of my screen behind the "related links" list, and I'm using widescreen 28" monitors at high resolution...

Comment: if you want to know the operator norm of $T : X \to Y$ you have to define what norms you are using on $X$ and $Y$... it seems here $X = C([0,3]),\|.\|_\infty$ and $Y = \mathbb{R},|.|$ but you didn't say it explicitly, and you wrote $\|Tu\|=\max_{x \in [0,3]}|\int_0^1u(x)dx-2\int_1^2u(x)dx+\int_2^3u(x)|$  which is quite... wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to show that there is a $z$ with $\|z\| = 1$ such that $|Tz| = 4$. Define $$z(x)= \begin{cases} 1 &x \in [0,1] \\
-1 &x \in [1,2] \\ 1 &x \in [2,3] \end{cases}$$

Edit: The function $z$ is not continuous. The desired result can be obtained by approximating it with mollifiers.

Comment: This is what I've tried but I've got stuck with $|Tz|=0$. The best one I found is  $sin(x \frac{\pi}{2})$ which gives me $|Tz|=3$

Comment: @Larisa I dont understand what you're saying. I edited my hint into a complete answer.

Comment: I thought that $z(x)$ has to be continuous on [0,3]. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me out where I was wrong with my reasoning :)

Comment: @Larisa oh, I thought we were talking about the space $L^1$ here, if we are talking about continuous functions with supremum norm, my answer is wrong.

Comment: @Please unaccept it so I can delete it.